# how unit test custom writable object using mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mapreduce, mockito

If I have a custom object class that implements Writable, what's the best way to test that serialization/deserialization are working correctly with unit tests with mockito? I was thinking of creating mock mapper/reducers but that seems way too unnecessary.

Example code:

```
public class CustomObj implements Writable {
    private String value;

    public CustomObj(String v) {
        value = v;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {
        out.writeChars(value);
    }

    public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {
        value = in.readLine();
    }
```

Comment: Please add some code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why use a mocking framework for this?

Round trip testing would be the simplest and quickest - so just serialize then deserialize and compare the two instances.  Don't use your equals() method for the comparison, even if it's well tested.

You will want to test the *edges* as well, for example to ensure transient fields are recreated/re-added on deserialization you can use [readResolve()](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t17491.html)

Some helpful tips can be found on [IBM DeveloperWorks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-serialtest/index.html)

Here's an example round trip test:

```
public class WritableTest {


    public class CustomObj implements Writable {
        private String value;

        public CustomObj(String v) {
            value = v;
        }

        @Override
        public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {
            out.writeUTF(value);
        }

        @Override
        public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {
            value = in.readUTF();
        }
    }


    @Test
    public void roundTripSerialization() throws Exception
    {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        DataOutput out = new DataOutputStream(byteOutput);

        CustomObj original = new CustomObj("originalValue");

        original.write(out);


        CustomObj deserialized = new CustomObj("you should really use add a zero arg constructor as well");

        DataInput in = new DataInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(byteOutput.toByteArray()));

        deserialized.readFields(in);


        Assert.assertEquals(original.value, deserialized.value);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I manually serialize/deserialize with the DataInput and DataOutput provided by the Writable interface?

Comment: @Jin, edited answer to include example code - the key to this is that using ByteArrayOutputStream allows us to acquire the serialized bytes and then we feed this back in using the ByteArrayInputStream.   NOTE: You code was failing because you weren't using symmetric read-write, see in the example above it's using readUTF and writeUTF .

Comment: Ah, okay I see, I was definitely overcomplicating things, thank you!